# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, появлялись все картинки разом

Tags: html

У меня есть код, в котором картинки появляются последовательно, а мне надо чтобы все сразу появилось, не подскажите?

```
HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Фото галерея</TITLE>


</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#CCCCFF"> Фото галерея </BODY>
 <img id="kartinka" src="1.jpg" alt="" />
<FORM>
<input TYPE="button" VALUE=" следующий " onClick="BgButton()">
<script language="javascript" src="joski.js" >
</script>
</FORM>


</BODY>



</HTML>
```

JAVA Joski.js

```
var pics = new Array(
  '1.jpg',
  '2.jpg',
  '3.jpg',
  '4.jpg',
  '5.jpg',
  '6.jpg',
  '7.jpg',
  '8.jpg',
  '9.jpg',
  '10.jpg',
);
var cur = -1;
function BgButton() {
  cur++;
  if (cur>4) cur=-1;
  document.getElementById('kartinka').src=pics[cur];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавлять новые теги , при нажатии на кнопку. С помощью цикла добавляем столько картинок, сколько элементов в массиве pics.

```
function BgButton() {
    for(i=1; i<pics.lenght; i++){
        document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += `<img src="${pics[i]}">`
    }
}
```